# How to link CSS to HTML file for Email Sending in a Django Project

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django

I trying to figure out a way to link CSS to an email html for sending.

I have used `inlinecss` but it didn't work out due to errors in locating the CSS file in static. My question is there any way to add CSS to my HTML email other than `Inlinecss`

In my template I have used using `Inlinecss`:

```
{% load inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss "/css/bootstrap.css" %}
TEXT
{% endinlinecss %}
```

Here is the complete path of the CSS file:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\static_in_env\css\bootstrap.css
```

After debugging I found that the reason is due to

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\static_root\\css\\bootstrap.css'
```

Here is the files structure:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Any ideas to  help link CSS to an email html for sending

Comment: Is there a reason you want to keep the email CSS in an external file? - It is best practice to keep email CSS in the HTML file itself. Most email clients will block external links and render your styles with unexpected results.